# Hornetq Error - Error starting service jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='jms-ra.rar'

Tags: java, eclipse, jms, hornetq, jboss-4.2.x

I am working on a task where I am integrating HornetQ 2.2.14 with JBoss 4.2.3.

I've successfully embedded HornetQ in JBoss 4.2.3 and created AS 4 profiles in JBoss 4.2.3 server directory, as default-with-hornetq and all-with-hornetq.

But, when I run JBoss 4.2.3 with following command:

```
    sh run.sh -c default-with-hornetq
```

Logger shows following error statements:

```
    15:28:51,301 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar
    15:28:51,321 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar
    15:28:51,336 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar
    15:28:51,350 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar
    15:28:51,758 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms-ra.rar/
    15:28:51,774 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='jms-ra.rar'
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
            at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter.initialiseTransactionManager(HornetQResourceAdapter.java:1740)
            at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter.start(HornetQResourceAdapter.java:224)
            at org.jboss.resource.deployment.RARDeployment.startService(RARDeployment.java:109)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.invoke(ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.java:124)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
```

Also errors related to queues which I have created in hornetq-jms.xml file are shown as :

```
            15:28:44,886 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:44 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: Waiting to obtain live lock
            15:28:44,933 INFO  [JournalStorageManager] Using NIO Journal
            15:28:44,951 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:44 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate warn
            WARNING: Security risk! It has been detected that the cluster admin user and password have not been changed from the installation                         default. Please see the HornetQ user guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to do this.
            15:28:45,208 INFO  [FileLockNodeManager] Waiting to obtain live lock
            15:28:45,208 INFO  [FileLockNodeManager] Live Server Obtained live lock
            15:28:46,756 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
            15:28:46,782 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
            15:28:46,792 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ServiceRequest
            15:28:46,800 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.MOQueue
            15:28:46,811 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.MTQueue
            15:28:46,819 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.NotificationQueue
            15:28:46,828 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.SMSQueue
            15:28:46,838 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.queueA
            15:28:46,846 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.eventQueue
            15:28:46,857 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.notificationQueue
            15:28:46,867 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:46 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.VodafoneMTQueue
            15:28:47,056 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c 127.0.0.1:5445 for CORE protocol
            15:28:47,061 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c 127.0.0.1:5455 for CORE protocol
            15:28:47,064 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:47 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: Server is now live
            15:28:47,065 ERROR [STDERR] 31 Aug, 2013 3:28:47 PM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate info
            INFO: HornetQ Server version 2.2.14.Final (HQ_2_2_14_FINAL, 122) [6a2175c5-1145-11e3-aaac-076c98ed9adc]) started
```

Thus queues are not created. I am unable to understand where the problem is. I am newbie to JBoss server. How can I solve this?

Comment: You wrote that you have *successfully* embedded HornetQ in JBoss 4.2.3. You have replaced the standard JBossMQ service? And HornetQ does not start? Which part is not working: Can you access the queues?

Comment: Queues are not getting created.So, I am unable to access them. I am not getting where the problem is.I tried deploying my EAR and I get DeploymentException and Nullpointer exception for Queues.

Comment: Exception is : Problem starting service jboss.j2ee:ear=services-1.0.ear,jar=bl-1.0.jar,name=SMSQueueConsumerBean,service=EJB3 org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Endpoint activation failed ra=jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='jms-ra.rar' activationSpec=org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@785727 destination=queue/SMSQueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15);-nested throwable:(java.lang.NullPointerException)